# Group Elements using XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt

I am in need to group `<math>` element and output `<math>` element only. I tried below XSLT.
Please note that  element can occur any where in the document and also the root element may also change

**XSLT 1.0 tried:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<xsl:key name="aKey" match="m:math" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
<xsl:copy-of select="key('aKey',m:math)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chapter xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<p>This is sample text
<a><math>This is math</math></a></p>
<a>This is a</a>
<math>This is math</math>
<a>This is a</a>
<a>This is a</a>
<b>This is <math>This is math</math>b</b>
<c>This is C</c>
</chapter>
```

Output Required:

```
<math>This is math</math>
<math>This is math</math>
<math>This is math</math>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="math | math//*" priority="2">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="math//@* | math//node()">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<math>This is math</math>
<math>This is math</math>
<math>This is math</math>
```

An approach using keys, which produces the same output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="kMath" match="math" use="''" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kMath', '')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" priority="-2">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  I've added an example above, but I don't think there's really a good reason to use keys here.

Comment: @siva why do you need a key since you only use it once, and match an element?? And I think it would be easier to just have a template match='math' and do a copy-of